# XML Validation error

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

I would like to know which part is not correct? I fixed one but another comes back.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!--
 Superstar Movies: Catalog of Movie and Actor Info.
 Author: Randy White
 Date:   6/28/2011

 Filename:         catalog.xml
 -->
 <!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
 <catalog>
<movie movieID="m0100" genre="drama">
    <title>Monster&apos;s Ball</title>
    <date>2001</date>
    <length>111 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0100 a0102"/>
</movie>
<actor actorID="a0100" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Halle Berry</name>
    <date>August 14, 1966</date>
    <birthplace>Cleveland, Ohio</birthplace>
    <role character="Leticia Musgrove" movie="m0100"/>
    <role character="Storm" movie="m0101"/>
</actor>
<actor actorID="a0102" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Billy Bob Thornton</name>
    <role character="Hank Grotowski" movie="m0100"/>
</actor>
<movie movieID="m0101" genre="fantasy">
    <title>X-Men</title>
    <year>2000</year>
    <length>104 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0100 a0103"/>
</movie>
<actor actorID="a0103" oscarWinner="no">
    <name>Ian McKellen</name>
    <role character="Magneto" movie="m0101"/>
    <role character="Gandolf" movie="m0105"/>
    <role character="Gandolf" movie="m0107"/>
</actor>
<movie movieID="m0105" genre="action" earningsRank="17">
    <title>Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring</title>
    <date>2001</date>
    <length>178 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0103"/>
</movie>
<movie movieID="m0107" genre="action" earningsRank="8">
    <title>Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King</title>
    <date>2003</date>
    <length>201 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0103"/>
</movie>
<actor actorID="a0101" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Tom Hanks</name>
    <date>July 9, 1956</date>
    <birthplace>Concord, California</birthplace>
    <role character="Captain John H. Miller" movie="m0102"/>
    <role character="Forrest Gump" movie="m0103"/>
    <role character="Andrew Beckett" movie="m0104"/>
</actor>
<movie movieID="m0102" genre="action" earningsRank="50">
    <title>Saving Private Ryan</title>
    <date>1998</date>
    <length>170 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0104"/>
</movie>
<actor actorID="a0104" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Matt Damon</name>
    <date>October 8, 1970</date>
    <birthplace>Cambridge, Massachusetts</birthplace>
    <role character="Private James Francis Ryan" movie="m0102"/>
</actor>
<movie movieID="m0103" genre="comedy" earningsRank="14">
    <title>Forrest Gump</title>
    <date>1994</date>
    <length>142 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0105 a0106"/>
</movie>
<actor actorID="a0105" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Sally Field</name>
    <birthplace>Pasadena, California</birthplace>
    <role character="Mrs. Gump" movie="m0103"/>
</actor>
<actor actorID="a0106">
    <name>Gary Sinise</name>
    <role character="Lt. Dan Taylor" movie="m0103"/>
    <role character="Ken Mattingly" movie="m0106"/>
</actor>
<movie movieID="m0104" genre="drama">
    <title>Philadelphia</title>
    <date>1993</date>
    <length>125 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0107"/>
</movie>
<movie movieID="m0106" genre="drama">
    <title>Apollo 13</title>
    <date>1995</date>
    <length>140 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0106"/>
</movie>
<actor actorID="a0107" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Denzel Washington</name>
    <role character="Joe Miller" movie="m0104"/>
</actor>
```

Error that I am getting

```
File C:\Users\Randy\Documents\XML\Solution Files\catalog.xml is not valid.
Content model of element 'movie' disallows element 'length' at this position.
    Error location: catalog / movie / length
    Details
        VC: Element Valid: Content model of element 'movie' disallows element 'length' at this position.
```

DTD File

```
    SuperStar Movies' DTD for XML Catalog documents
    Author: Randy White
    Date:   6/28/2011

    Filename:         catalog.dtd
    -->

    <!ELEMENT catalog (movie|actor)*>

    <!ELEMENT movie (title, date,year,length,topBilledActors)>
    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT length (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT topBilledActors EMPTY>
     <!ATTLIST movie movieID ID #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST movie genre (action|comedy|drama|fantasy) #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST movie earningsRank CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST topBilledActors actorIDs IDREFS #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT actor (name, date?, birthplace?, role+)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT birthplace (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT role EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST actor actorID ID #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST actor oscarWinner (yes|no) "no">
    <!ATTLIST role character CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST role movie IDREF #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: The element "length" is not allowed in the position that you have it. Can you post the DTD so we can tell you where it is supposed to be?

Comment: Ive been trying but I dont see how to post it

Comment: Iam not allowed to answer my own question to show you. Any ideas?

Comment: <!ELEMENT catalog (movie|actor)*> <!ELEMENT movie (title, date,year,length,topBilledActors)> <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)> <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)> <!ELEMENT length (#PCDATA)> <!ELEMENT topBilledActors EMPTY> <!ATTLIST movie movieID ID #REQUIRED> <!ATTLIST movie genre (action|comedy|drama|fantasy) #REQUIRED> <!ATTLIST movie earningsRank CDATA #IMPLIED> <!ATTLIST topBilledActors actorIDs IDREFS #REQUIRED>

Comment: Click "edit" to edit your question. Also, be sure to include the entire DTD.

Comment: i will update my answer with what i would do to the dtd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the DTD, I can see that `movie` has to have exactly one `title`, `date`, `year`, `length`, and `topBilledActors` (**in that order**).

Some of your movie elements don't contain all of the necessary elements. Either you need to fix the XML, or your DTD needs modifications.

For example, the first `movie` element is missing a `year`:

```
<movie movieID="m0100" genre="drama">
    <title>Monster&apos;s Ball</title>
    <date>2001</date>
    <length>111 minutes</length>
    <topBilledActors actorIDs="a0100 a0102"/>
</movie>
```

I would lean toward DTD modifications since you have multiple ATTLIST declarations for movie.

This is how I would modify your DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT catalog (movie|actor)*>

<!ELEMENT movie (title?,date?,year?,length?,topBilledActors?)> 
<!ATTLIST movie 
          movieID ID #REQUIRED 
          genre (action|comedy|drama|fantasy) #REQUIRED 
          earningsRank CDATA #IMPLIED> 

<!ELEMENT topBilledActors EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST topBilledActors 
          actorIDs IDREFS #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT actor (name, date?, birthplace?, role+)>
<!ATTLIST actor 
          actorID ID #REQUIRED
          oscarWinner (yes|no) "no">

<!ELEMENT role EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST role 
          character CDATA #REQUIRED
          movie IDREF #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT length (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT birthplace (#PCDATA)>
```

Notice that the children of `movie` are now optional (? = zero or one occurrence).

Also notice how I merged the ATTLIST declarations and put them with their element declarations. Moving them just under the element declaration makes the DTD much easier to read.

Comment: What would I add to the DTD file so that it doesnt always look for those in order?

Comment: If you wanted to change `movie` so that order didn't matter at all, you could change it to this: `<!ELEMENT movie (title|date|year|length|topBilledActors)+>`

Comment: You're very welcome. If this answer is sufficient, please consider accepting it.